# How to fit arbitrary images into subplots without changing alignment in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-gridspec

I have a code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


def format_axes(fig):
    for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)


# gridspec inside gridspec
fig = plt.figure()

gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, figure=fig)

gs00 = gs0[0,0].subgridspec(2, 3, wspace=0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[:, :-1])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[0, -1])


gs01 = gs0[0,1].subgridspec(2, 3, wspace=0)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs01[:, :-1])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs01[0, -1])

gs10 = gs0[1,0].subgridspec(1, 1)

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs10[0, 0])

gs11 = gs0[1,1].subgridspec(1, 1)

ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs11[0, 0])

format_axes(fig)


for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

that gives a [draft of the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfl5Z.png).
And I need to fill these subplots with arbitrary shaped images, like this

```
img1 = np.random.rand(10, 20)
img2 = np.random.rand(15, 25)
img3 = np.random.rand(20, 30)
img4 = np.random.rand(25, 35)
img5 = np.random.rand(30, 40)
img6 = np.random.rand(35, 45)

ax1.imshow(img1)
ax2.imshow(img2)
ax3.imshow(img3)
ax4.imshow(img4)
ax5.imshow(img5)
ax6.imshow(img6)
```

but it changes positions of subplots and their aspect ratios ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNwao.png)). I also need to keep aspect ratio for images.
How can I plot it and keep the alignment and aspect ratios?

I tried to extend my images manually so they have the same aspect ratio as subplots in draft figure. In my view it could solve the problem with alignment. But I didn't succeed in extracting these aspect ratios.

Comment: You have too many constraints for arbitrary shaped images to be aligned with each other.  It’s not really clear what you are after as a final product

Comment: I could imagine 2 approaches here. 
First it crops the edges of images so they just fill subplots on draft figure, 
The second is it places an image into center of a subplot in such a way that the picture touches the edges of the subplot vertically or horizontally (depending on its shape). It left empty space to the other edges of the subplot but I can fill it later as background

Comment: For the latter you can do `ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')`. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need to specify the `aspect` argument in your call, by either using [axis.set_aspect](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect) or by explicitly setting the `aspect` in your [ax.imshow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html).

```
ax1.imshow(img1, aspect='auto')
ax2.imshow(img2, aspect='auto')
ax3.imshow(img3, aspect='auto')
ax4.imshow(img4, aspect='auto')
ax5.imshow(img5, aspect='auto')
ax6.imshow(img6, aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I need to keep aspect ratios for images as well, so it is not my case.
I see here 2 options. First it crops the edges of images so they fits into draft, or it places an image into center of a subplot in such a way that the picture touches the edges of the subplot vertically or horizontally (depending on its shape) and there is empty space to the other edges of the subplot (which I can fill later as background)